# Multidimensional Array Slicing in Python

Tags: python

I am stuck with the slicing of a 3D array:

`x = np.array([np.arange(0, 10), None, None])`

`X = x[:, None, None]`

How can I visualize this? Phrased differently, how can I understand what is going on here?

Comment: `np` stands for Numerical Python. Here I am trying to slice a 3D array, but I am not sure how I can visualize it.

Comment: To understand what is going on, spend a lot of time reading the documentation and play around with the concepts till things start to gel.  That said, it is entirely unclear what you are trying to accomplish with those lines of code.